# Monitor stored data size in Firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

Firestore costs are based on document operations and on size of stored data.
In the Firebase console, we can easily track number of document operations but I don't find any place where I can track size of stored data.

I have only found in Google Cloud Console (in App Engine > Quotas) a metric corresponding to the amount of stored data in gigabyte stored the current day, but not the total amount of stored data.

**Is there a means of monitoring total size of stored data (ideally with indexes included) ?**

Comment: If you are using **GCP**’s Firestore in Native or Datastore mode, you should be able to see the total size (including indexes) in the [Datastore Dashboard](https://console.cloud.google.com/project/_/datastore/stats), in Cloud Console

Comment: No, it's not possible to access to datastore data if Firestore is used in Native mode.

Comment: You're right. Apparently, the size is being displayed there only for the Firestore in Datastore mode.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that the only available option at this moment is to calculate the storage size for Cloud Firestore in Native mode [manually](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/storage-size).

I have submitted a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/156576744) asking to implement a solution that would display the size. I'd recommend you to star that request to be notified once there is an update in the thread.

Comment: Thanks for submitting the feature request. It's ridiculous that this information is not displayed because they must have it for the billing... On every project I built with FB I am thinking in the end if it wasn't better to build it as standard application because I always run into something new which is "impossible" - like this one.

Comment: Came here to say the same thing... How am I supposed to be billed if they won't tell me how much I'm using? Are we just supposed to wait until the next billing cycle and guess how much we used based on how much it cost? Makes it really hard to plan or optimize.